# run sql commands in cmd from a file through java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, command-line, cmd

Let's say my Netbeans Java project is located at C:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/Netbeans Project/JavaProject.

And my sql file is located in the same directory as my java project.
Now, suppose I want to run this sql file at C:\iclockSvr\mysql\bin folder, I have to copy my sql file to this folder, because using the absolute path of that sql file in my command doesn't work, as shown below.

[image]

How do I automate this whole process of running the sql file through java, preferably without moving that file to this( C:\iclockSvr\mysql\bin) directory?

Comment: i'm new to stackoverflow, so someone please embed that image from the link in the question itself, so that people don't have to navigate somewhere else to see it.

Comment: Haven't you noticed the **Image** button in the [edit]or (short-cut *Ctrl+G*), which perfectly supports in embedding images? You can also refer to this help page: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) Anyway, code and error messages are better embedded as text (find the **Code Sample** button, short-cut *Ctrl+K*), so others could simply copy it.

Comment: Your filespec contains spaces so you need to enclose it in double quotes (`"`) to use it as an argument at the Windows command prompt.

Comment: @GordThompson, yes it worked.